# how to access variable value from within a resize function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an else..if statement that assigns a value to a variable based on the `window.width`, what I would like to do is then use this value inside a `window.resize` but at the moment get `'undefined'` for `currentSize` the value. What should I be doing in order to get the value?

JS

```
//Code ran onload
if(windowWidth >= 924) {
    incrementValue = 3;
    currentSize = 'desktop';
}
else if(windowWidth > 615 && windowWidth < 924) {
    incrementValue = 2;
    currentSize = 'tablet';
}
else {
    incrementValue = 1;
    currentSize = 'mobile';
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    windowWidth = $(window).width();

    if(windowWidth >= 924) {
        incrementValue = 3;
        var newSize = 'desktop';
    }
    else if(windowWidth > 615 && windowWidth < 924) {
        incrementValue = 2;
        var newSize = 'tablet';
    }
    else {
        incrementValue = 1;
        var newSize = 'mobile';
    }

    console.log(currentSize); //'undefined'
    if (currentSize !== newSize) {
        var currentSize = newSize;

        incrementTotal = 0;
        slideIndex = 0;

        //Reset slider to start
        $carouselSlides.css( 'left', 0 );
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please post a more complete version of the code? It would be useful to see how you define windowWidth.

Comment: which variable is that? Based on your code, `currentSize` should be visible and `incrementValue` and `slideIndex` are implied globals anyway (which is a bad thing). Hard to say anthing about `windowWidth` though...

Comment: additional code added, hope this helps

Comment: @styler: **A warm suggestion** As it seems you don't know what keyword `var` does to variables in Javascript because sometimes you're not using it (and you should) and other times you're using it (but you shouldn't). Therefore it will help you tremendously if you learn about variable scope in Javascript. It will help you in the future with such issues you just had.

Comment: @styler: see my answer for better pattern...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't redefine `currentSize` with `var` like this

```
if (currentSize !== newSize) {
    var currentSize = newSize;
```

Remove the `var`

```
if (currentSize !== newSize) {
    currentSize = newSize;
```

Here is an example which allows you to reproduce or eliminate your error depending on the presence of `var`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/94zVg/2/
- http://jsfiddle.net/94zVg/3/

Comment: That's not the case with Javascript you know... Javascript only knows about function scope and nothing about code block scope. So if you declare your variable within `if` statement it will be visible within the whole function scope anyway... AFAIK all variables declared during function code blocks are in compilations moved to the top of the function. It's true that such re-declarations are very bad practice though.

Comment: Now you've found it yes. `currentSize` redefinition was actually the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
//global scope
var currentSize = 'desktop', incrementTotal = 0, incrementValue = 0, slideIndex = 0, $carouselSlides = $('#carouselSlides');

function windowResize(windowWidth) {
    var data = [];
    if (windowWidth >= 924) {
        data = ['desktop', 3];
    } else if (windowWidth > 615 && windowWidth < 924) {
        data = ['tablet', 2];
    } else {
        data = ['mobile', 1];
    }
    return data.length ? data : false;
}


$(window).resize(function() {
    var windowWidth = $(this).width();
    var data = windowResize(windowWidth);
    // data[0] = desktop, tablet OR mobile
    // data[1] = 1, 2 OR 3
    incrementValue = data[1];

    if (currentSize !== data[0]) {
        currentSize = data[0];

        incrementTotal = 0;
        slideIndex = 0;

        //Reset slider to start
        $carouselSlides.css('left', 0);
    }    

    // set the style for the current screen size   
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your newSize is out of scope:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   windowWidth = $(window).width();
var newSize =0;
   if(windowWidth >= 924){
      incrementValue = 3;
        newSize = 'desktop';
    } else if(windowWidth > 615 && windowWidth < 924) {
      incrementValue = 2;
      newSize = 'tablet';
    } else {
      incrementValue = 1;
      newSize = 'mobile';
    }

    if (currentSize !== newSize) {
      var currentSize = newSize;

      incrementTotal = 0;
      slideIndex = 0;

      //Reset slider to start
      $carouselSlides.css( 'left', 0 );
    }
  });
```